# using rails how do i only show the id submitted via a text box from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a table full of information at the moment, Ideally i need the information from a database table to be viewed via a link.

I only have the controller and some standard html (the html is just a h1 tag at the moment)

The HTML will be standard throughout like a template.

The way i'm seeing what i want in my head is the users will get a link which would be `events_prev/{{id from DB here}}` and depending on the ID the information on the page will be populated from the corrisponsing DB Row

Heres my controller

```
class Events::EventsPrevController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.where(id: id)
  end

  def show
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

Sorry if its super confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to rails.

Ok, there's a couple of things that will get you in the right directions.  Firstly, you REALLY need to do a little reading to understand how the controller and the routes and the views are linked together in rails, that'll help you tons.

But moving on to your specific issues:

## Parameters:

All data passed via a url (get, post, put, doesn't matter the method) is available in the controller in an array object called `params` - So that means when want to access the data the user submitted, you'll use something like

```
@event = Event.where(id: params[:id])
```

## Routes:

It looks like you're trying to use the index page.  In rails index is a RESTful route which generally points to a collection of model objects.  The show route will point to an individual object so you should instead make your link point to the show path instead of the index path.

You can view the routes available on a model on a command line using:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

An example of what your routes might look like:

```
      prev_events GET    /prev_events(.:format)                prev_events#index
                  POST   /prev_events(.:format)                prev_events#create
   new_prev_event GET    /prev_events/new(.:format)            prev_events#new
  edit_prev_event GET    /prev_events/:id/edit(.:format)       prev_events#edit
       prev_event GET    /prev_events/:id(.:format)            prev_events#show
                  PATCH  /prev_events/:id(.:format)            prev_events#update
                  PUT    /prev_events/:id(.:format)            prev_events#update
                  DELETE /prev_events/:id(.:format)            prev_events#destroy
```

## Link

Based on the routing table, you now should see that the link you need your users to click on might look like this (given that `event` is your object:

```
<%= link_to event.title, event_path(event.id) %>
```

or shortcutted

```
<%= link_to event.title, event %>
```

## View

For the view this is entirely dependent on the data in the Event model. Since the data is stored in `@event` you'll simple use the attributes on the event model to render the html however use like, e.g.

```
<h3><%= @event.title %></h3>
<span><%= @event.start_time %></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [Rails controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html): by default the action `index` is used to show all of the records and what you're talking about should belong to the `show` action. The default [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) take care of the id passing to your show action.

Answer (score 0):

Index action is mean to show list of items in view and Show action is used to show a single item.

what you are doing in `index` is actually mean to be in `show` action.

Reason:

```
@events = Event.where(id: id)
```

this line will give u a single record in every case it means it should be in Show action.

your code should look like:

```
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    [your logic: what you want to do with that @event]
  end
```